# Replacing double slashes on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, url-rewriting

Is there any way to rewrite url in order to replace the double slashes (//) of the URL in IIS 8.0 on azure. The following two solutions below work in my local iis (Microsoft-IIS / 8.0), the two servers are IIS 8.0 running on azure locally have not tried a thousand ways and nothing works, thanks in advance.

solution 1 work locally, doesn't work on azure

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string requestUrl = Request.ServerVariables["REQUEST_URI"];
    string rewriteUrl = Request.ServerVariables["UNENCODED_URL"];
    if (rewriteUrl.Contains("//") && !requestUrl.Contains("//"))
        Response.RedirectPermanent(requestUrl);
}
```

solution 2 the same results work locally, doesn't work on azure

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove multiple slashes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{REQUEST_URI}" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL}" pattern="([^/]*)/{2,}([^/]*)" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Do you put the URL Rewrite module rules in `system.webServer` or in `system.web`section. The rewrite rules must all go under `system.webServer`!

Comment: Yes is under System.Webserver, i have anothers rules and all of them works properly, this is the only one rule that doesn't work, the interesting is that work fine in my local mahcine and in my production deployment doesn't work

Comment: that Rule that you have pasted here does NOT work for me neither local, nor in Azure. I am working on VS 2013.3, IIS 8 Express / 8.5 Full, Windows 8.1. I created just plain MVC 5 project and put the rule you provided (rewrite rule in web.config). It simply does not work - neither local, nor in Azure.